# How does ping 1.1 convert to ping 1.0.0.1?

Tags: ipv4

I need the rules for these ip address shorthands.

```
C:\Users\avina>ping 1.1

Pinging 1.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 1.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=58
Reply from 1.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=58
Reply from 1.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=58
Reply from 1.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=58

Ping statistics for 1.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 4ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old relic from the days of classful IPv4 networks.

When you had no subnetting, just exactly one class-B network with 2 octets for the host address, in some cases it would have been convenient to just use a linear numbering 0-65535 (0000h-FFFFh) for all your hosts, instead of two separate numbers. *(At least that's what I assume the reason was.)*

So the BSD networking software would accept `x.y.(z*256+t)` as alternative way of writing class-B addresses, in addition to the usual `x.y.z.t`. For example the address 128.42.1.6 could be written as "128.42.262" instead.

The same also worked for class-A addresses as `x.(y*65536+z*256+t)` – for example, the address 10.1.33.27 could be written as "10.74011".

(As a side note, for some reason it would also accept the numbers in octal and hex. Actually it gets clearer if you write the above examples in hex: 10.1.33.27 is "0xA.0x1.0x21.0x1B", and 10.74011 is "0xA.0x1211B".)

This survived in many systems which faithfully reproduced the same IP address parsing code, including Windows or Linux (and only recently purged from OpenBSD).

This *Super User* post describes it in more detail: https://superuser.com/revisions/486904/3

Answer (score 1):

This follows the (rarely used) convention that middle `0` octets can be omitted in writing - this is much more prominent in IPv6 with the double `::` notation.

`1.1` expands to `1.0.0.1` like e.g. `127.1` expands to `127.0.0.1`. Likewise `a.b.c` expands to `a.b.0.c` and even just `a` expands to `0.0.0.a` (consistent with the *unsigned 32-bit* notation).

In reality, an IPv4 address is an unsigned 32-bit integer. The common `a.b.c.d` notation is really `a<<24|b<<16|c<<8|d`. When only `a.b` is used it's `a<<24|b` and `a.b.c` is really `a<<24|b<<16|c`. (Thx grawity!)

Comment: No, `a.b.c` expands to `a.b.(c / 256).(c % 256)`.

Comment: @grawity You're correct - this is even more obscure than the `a.b` notation. Likewise `a.b` expands to `a.(b/65536).((b%65536)/256).(b%256)`. I don't think anyone wants to use that...